# phantom.exit(-1) doesn't work when called from another function

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, phantomjs, exit-code

I'm using PhantomJS to run JavaScript. There's a function `phantom.exit()` that accepts exit code as 1st argument.

Here's how it works...

```
var page = require("webpage").create(),
    $ = require("jquery")

page.open("http://127.0.0.1:8081/", function (status) {
    var title = page.evaluate(function() {
        return $("title").text()
    })
    phantom.exit(-1)
})
```

Returned exit code is -1 or 255 as expected.

My problem is that I need to exit script when my function is called. My function contains `phantom.exit(-1)`.

```
var page = require("webpage").create(),
    $ = require("jquery")

function foo() {
    phantom.exit(-1)
}

page.open("http://127.0.0.1:8081/", function (status) {
    var title = page.evaluate(function() {
        return $("title").text()
    })
    foo()
    phantom.exit()
})
```

Problem is that `phantom.exit(-1)` that's in `foo()` function is not called and exit code is 0.

There's a workaround to check for return value in my function and call `phantom.exit()` manually, but it's not as I want it... Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the version of PhantomJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possibility, that your `foo` function call to `phantom.exit` output got overriden by the `page.open` callbacks one.

Hence, calling `foo()` set exit code to -1.
Afterwards, calling `phantom.exit` without parameter, set the exit code back to 0.

Because phantom itself, probably, returns the exit code after everything has been executed, you got 0, with no signs of -1.